# Getting error response on post request for the data filling page jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can anybody help me in solving for error message in response header in jmeter.
Recorded a script from blazemeter in one page comes with data filling with date and all but after the post request in return of response I got object moved to error page that is 404.
[Post request response message shown as like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m6Tn.png)

Comment: It will better for you to provide some screenshots about your HTTP request; like header and body of the request and response. Also you should check if a token is necessary in your request's header, maybe you forgot to add that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to the error page placeholder because  you are either sending a [malformed/bad request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) or there is missing/improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)

If you can successfully run your request in i.e. browser you can check the request details using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (Network tab or equivalent) and cross check all the details (URL, [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header), Body, etc.) with what JMeter sends, it can be visualized using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Comment: Yes i have checked with network tab and even in view  result tree response but the data which I am posting is not storing to database ..any idea?